# Loop through SQL data and compare to itself using Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am pulling data from SQL server and using Python to reformat and compare it to data in a NoSQL document database.

My return set of data from SQL looks like this:
('1', 'a')
('2', 'b')
('2', 'c')
('3', 'd')
('3', 'e')
The first attribute is the ID, and that ID may be repeated multiple times with a second unique identifier attached to it. 
In order to compare the SQL data to JSON data in my NoSQL db, I need to put the data in the following format:

```
{
'ID':2,
'IDInfo': 
    {'OtherID':'b'},
    {'OtherID':'c'}
}
```

Where I am struggling is how to compare a list to itself. I have to compare the first row's ID to the second row's ID, then the second row's ID to the third row's ID and so forth. I understand how to do this kind of looping in JavaScript, but I can't figure it out in Python.

I have tried looping through the list starting at index 0, and then looping through the same list again at index 1 and comparing those IDs:

```
for index,row in enumerate(sqlResult):
    ID = row[0]
    i = index+1
    for index1,nextRow in enumerate(sqlResult, start=i):
        if (index1<i+1):
            nextRowId = nextRow[0]
        if (nextRowId == ID):
            #logic to append OtherID to a dynamically created object.
    print(ID,nextRowId) #Used this line to make sure the I was comparing the first ID to the next row's ID.
```

However, this logic only ends up looping/returning the first row in my list of rows. I am utterly baffled by the concept of looping through the same object twice in python and comparing values. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it could be something like this:

```
>>> sql = [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('2', 'c'), ('3', 'd'), ('3', 'e')]
>>> json = {}
>>> for a,b in sql:
...  json[a] = [b] if a not in json else json[a]+[b] # Ternary Operator
>>> json
{'1': ['a'], '3': ['d', 'e'], '2': ['b', 'c']}
>>> json.items()
[('1', ['a']), ('3', ['d', 'e']), ('2', ['b', 'c'])]
>>> [{a:json[a]} for a in json] # List Comprehension
[{'1': ['a']}, {'3': ['d', 'e']}, {'2': ['b', 'c']}]
>>> formatted_json = [ {'ID':int(i),'IDInfo':[{'OtherID':v} for v in json[i]] } for i in json]  # Dictionary Comprehension in a List Comprehension
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(formatted_json)
[{'ID': 1, 'IDInfo': [{'OtherID': 'a'}]},
 {'ID': 3, 'IDInfo': [{'OtherID': 'd'}, {'OtherID': 'e'}]},
 {'ID': 2, 'IDInfo': [{'OtherID': 'b'}, {'OtherID': 'c'}]}]
```

There's also a "json" module in Python for standard encoding/decoding/formatting. Hope it helps!